# How to move data inside observable collection from 1 page to another page?

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-7

I want to pass the value in observable collection from page 1 to page 2. How can I pass it using a global variable?

```
public pg1()
{    
    InitializeComponent();
    proxy.FindOrderCompleted += new EventHandler<FindOrderCompletedEventArgs>(proxy_FindOrderCompleted);
    proxy.FindOrderAsync(custemail);
}

void proxy_FindOrderCompleted(object sender, FindOrderCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.ItemsSource = e.Result;
    ObservableCollection<Order> Orders = this.listBox1.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<Order>;
}
```

After assign it at xmal as

```
public ObservableCollection <Order> Orders  
{ 
    get; set; 
}

public List<Order> FindOrder(string custemail, string orderstatus)
        {
            var findorder = from r in order.Orders where (r.CustEmail  == custemail && r.OrderStatus == orderstatus ) select r;
            return findorder.ToList();
        }
```

How to get the assign it to global?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what FindOrderCompletedEventArgs are, but you should do

```
void proxy_FindOrderCompleted(object sender, FindOrderCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Orders = new ObservableCollection<Order>(e.Result);
    listBox1.ItemsSource = Orders;
}
```

Comment: The collection is under void proxy_FindOrderCompleted..Then how can i assign observable collection become public void?

Comment: Huh? The method is setting the property 'Orders' within it. The method is still a void b/c it does not return anything